# pass post value to the query in pagination

Tags: post, pagination, codeigniter-3

Here i want to pass the post value to the query written in pagination but unfortunately the query is not getting the post value while going to the second page. in order to get the value i had placed the post value in session then also its not passing the value so how can i overcome from this

```
public function sales_report(){
      $data['start_date'] = $start_date = $this->input->post('start_date');
      $data['end_date'] = $end_date = $this->input->post('end_date');
      $data['type'] = $type = $this->input->post('type');
      $user_id=$this->input->post('user_id',FALSE);

      $this->session->set_userdata('s_date', $start_date);
      $this->session->set_userdata('e_date', $end_date);

      $s_date=$this->session->userdata('s_date');
      $e_date=$this->session->userdata('e_date');


      $limit = 10;
      $config['base_url'] = base_url().'app/report/sales_report/';
      $config['per_page'] = $limit;
      $config['next_tag_open'] = '<div class="next">';
      $config['next_tag_close'] = '</div>';
      $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
      $config['uri_rsegment'] = 4;
      $page_number = ($this->uri->segment(4)) ? $this->uri->segment(4) : 1;
      $offset = ($page_number == 1) ? 0 : ($page_number * $limit) - $limit;


      $config['total_rows'] = $this->Report_model->count_date_wise_sales_info($s_date,$e_date);
      $data['headers'] =  $this->Report_model->get_date_wise_sales_info($s_date,$e_date,$config['per_page'],$offset);

      $this->load->library('pagination',$config);
      $data['page_links'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
      $data['products']=$this->db->order_by('id','desc')->get('products')->result();
      $this->load->view('app/reports/sales_report',$data);
}
```

please help me to solve

Comment: make sure your post values are `not empty` and also have loaded your `session` library in controller or in `autoload.php`

Comment: my post value is not empty and i had loaded session library

Comment: Please provide your Model code where you're not getting values passed.

Answer (score 0):

for passing PHP value to jquery or javascript you must create a script tag in PHP file like this I want to pass base_url to jquery.
`example.php`

```
<?php

<script type="text/javascript">
     base_url = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>";
</script>

?>
```